# Como puedo configurar el paquete de postgres para Flutter?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando conectarme con un dispositivo físico a PostgreSQL con Flutter usando el paquete postgres, pero me lanza esta excepción:

```
SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 34910
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
Future<void> testConnection() async {
  final conn = PostgreSQLConnection(
    '192.168.43.11',
    5432,
    'MuestreoParcelas',
    username: 'postgres',
    password: '***********',
    useSSL: true,
  );
  await conn.open();
  final PostgreSQLResult query = await conn.query('SELECT * FROM app_user');
  print(query.columnDescriptions);
  await conn.close();
}
```

Estuve buscando y si estoy en un dispositivo físico, no puedo usar localhost sino poner la dirección IP del servidor al que quiero que se conecte, en este caso estoy usando de servidor una laptop. Tengo ambos dispositivos conectados por WiFi a otro dispositivo que es el que creó el punto de acceso. ¿Cómo pudiera solucionar ese error y conectar mi dispositivo físico con la base de datos?